# How do I list a url to a list that has multiple content types (Sharepoint Online)

Tags: javascript, css

I have a jquery data table that displays sharepoint list data I currently have a column in the table that displays a link to the record.

I need to update that URL to add a variable based on the content type:
An example of this is....

http://www.domain/"+ var1 +"/editifs.aspx?ID="+ id +"

The "var1" is just a variable for the content type of the record

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field to each content type, perhaps 'CT', with the default value set as the corresponding content type name. This should then allow you to build to url via a calculated column